# How to access json values in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have multiple json data like below

```
"data":{
      "test":{
        "2.0.1":1
      },
      "test1":{
        "2.0.2":1
      },
      "test3":{
        "2.0.3":1
      }
    }
```

I wanted to print the data using python script in the below format. Please help.

```
data:2.0.1
data:2.0.2
data:2.0.3
```

Below is my code. it print everything in a single line

```
import json

json_data = open('test.json')

json = json.loads(json_data.read())

mydict = json

myitems = mydict.items()

for x in mydict.items():

    key = x[0]

    value = x[1]

    print(key, value)
```

Comment: What is the actual output? Please add that info to the question.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON cannot start with a key. Does your JSON start with `{`, followed by `"data":`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

with open(filename) as f:    
    myDict = json.load(f)       #Note you can use json.load to read from file

for key, value in myDict.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        print(key, v.keys()[0])
```

**Output:**

```
(u'data', u'2.0.1')
(u'data', u'2.0.2')
(u'data', u'2.0.3')
```

Comment: Or `for v in value.values():`, since your not using `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate which Python version you are using.

For Python3, you'd adapt [Rakesh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422368/1923870) as follows (the `list(test_data)[0]` bit on the last line is the one relevant here):

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:    
    myDict = json.load(f) 

for k, v in myDict.items():
    for test_data in v.values():
        print("{}:{}".format(k, list(test_data)[0]))
```

Note I also adapted the output to include a colon, so it mirrors what you said you wanted the output to look like, and I only loop through the values of the data dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I have similar values in the same json file with different keys. How can I print all the "test" values together then "test1" and "test2" ?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, or how your JSON file is structured. If one of the answers helped you solve your original question, I suggest you accept it. Otherwise edit your original question (and maybe indicate where you've expanded it) to clarify what you want to know, or to add your related/follow-up question. If your JSON file is actually more complex than the snippet you shared, it would have been a good idea to include all relevant info from the start for those who spend time looking at your question – something to remember for future questions.

Comment: Yes, the solution provided by you answered my original question.Sorry for not mentioning it earlier.Thanks for that. My further question is, how can I get the below expected out put from the json file

{
  "data": {
    "test": {
      "2.0.1": 1
    },
    "test1": {
      "2.0.2": 1
    },
    "test3": {
      "2.0.3": 1
    }
  },
  "data1": {
    "test": {
      "3.0.1": 1
    },
    "test1": {
      "3.0.2": 1
    },
    "test3": {
      "3.0.3": 1
    }
  }

Expected output 

data:2.0.2
data1:3.0.1

Comment: If an answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark, otherwise amend your question, or ask a new question altogether. (Note though that edits to a question several days after it was originally asked won't be seen by many folks.) Questions in comments get lost and put the onus on helping you solve your problem on the person the comment is in reply to, which is counter to how SO works.

Comment: Btw. I had a look at the above new JSON - did you test the solution with it? Because for me it returns `data:2.0.1
data:2.0.2
data:2.0.3
data1:3.0.1
data1:3.0.2
data1:3.0.3` (each on a separate line). If you expected something else, it's impossible to tell from the example output you gave.

Comment: @Martin If the solution helped you, please accept it so your question gets marked as answered.